# Mac boots no more

Tags: macbook-pro

I upgraded my ram about three months ago and then it had random restarts, then I checked disk utility to that my main hardisk wasn't good and couldn't be repaired. But then I did a safe boot and again everything was normal. Then after 3 days again random restarts, safe booted and everything was fine then finally after 3 days it randomly restarted and didn't boot. Mean while o had installed el Capitan beta 1 on another partion. Then I installed Yosemite on a SD card from my friends Mac book and booted from it on my Mac. Everything seemed fine. I backed up data and reinstalled osx on it. Till today everything was fine of reinstallation of osx when suddenly I restarted. I tried to do a safe boot and restart but after safe boot when I clicked restart while restarting it would show a prohibitory sign then the apple logo then again the prohbitory sign and again apple logo and again prohibitory sign and apple logo with loading bar but it won't boot into my main hard disk bit into the El Capitan partion and even if I try to hold option while booting and select main disk it does the same dance and boots into El Capitan. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You did a lot of installing of operating systems including installing a beta version of an operating system; which, by the way, is ***not*** in any way an accepted method to diagnose issues.

However, I noticed you never addressed the single causality that probably is the issue:

> I upgraded my ram about three months ago and then it had random
>   restarts,

- Have you tried resetting you [NVRAM?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)
- Have you tried removing the RAM you installed?

Those would be the first two steps I would take before I embark on a OS installation and re-installation journey.

Comment: Actually I wanted check el Capitan out not diagnose via it, secondly I did reset nvram and I didn't try removing the ram installed as I thought it might be a software issue and I didn't upgrade the ram myself but had it done by some computer genius, and so I wasn't very keen on doing myself. I have an appointment with the same guy tomorrow so let's we what the results are ( is it possible that I may not have to reinstall the software by playing around with the ram?) Thanks!

Comment: You won't have to reinstall any software for a memory upgrade.  In fact, there are relatively few instances where you have to re-install due to a hardware change.

Comment: No I mean no that I get the prohibitory sign, is it possible that after the ram is better, my Mac would boot?

Comment: Can you explain the "prohibitory sign?"  If possible, take a picture with you cell phone and post it here.

Comment: http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e184/eseverino/IMG_0004-1.jpg.           Refer to this picture

Comment: I also want to tell the ram I upgraded is 1333mhz whereas apple says 1600mhz for Mac book pro mid 2012(my model) so is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that you pull the drive, put it in an enclosure and try to reformat it from another system.

Or just get a new drive and try installing fresh.

The other issue could be bad ram assuming you checked the ram you bought was fully compatible. I did but knockoff ram once that said it was all good but turned out not to be.